# OpenVPN on DD-WRT Internet connection problem

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, dd-wrt

I have a DD-WRT router configured with OpenVPN server. I can remote into the network from an external client, but when i do I cannot access anything on the internet. i.e. only LAN connections. When I try to ping Google I get nothing.

Additional Config;

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
management localhost 16
```

Firewall;

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

[image: Server Config]

Comment: "Redirect default gateway" should be enabled; I also recommend "Tunnel UDP MSS-Fix" to be enabled. Then you should run also to your iptables: iptables -i eth0 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE  - eth0 if eth0 is facing Internet

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this line to the firewall settings:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```